# How to perform liftover from 38 to 37 in R?

Tags: r, python, genomics, gwas, liftover

I have some gwas summary statistics in GRCh38 that I want to lift to GRCh37. I am trying to liftover in R using this code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
library(rtracklayer)
library(GenomicRanges)

rm(list=ls())

gwas_data <- fread("/gwas_sumstats_allchr.txt")
chain_file <- "/chain_files/hg38ToHg19.over.chain"
chain <- import.chain(chain_file)

# Convert to GRanges object (assuming GENPOS is 1-based)
gwas_ranges <- GRanges(
  seqnames = Rle(gwas_data$CHROM),
  ranges = IRanges(start = gwas_data$GENPOS - 1, end = gwas_data$GENPOS) # Convert to 0-based start
)

gwas_ranges$seqnames <- paste0("chr", gwas_ranges$seqnames)

# Perform the liftover
liftover_output <- liftOver(gwas_ranges, chain)

# Extract successful liftover
liftover_success <- liftover_output$`output`

# Convert the results back to a data frame (convert positions back to 1-based)
result <- data.frame(
  CHROM = as.character(seqnames(liftover_success)),
  GENPOS = start(liftover_success) + 1  # Convert back to 1-based position
)

# Print or save the result
print(head(result))
```

However this doesn't work and I am getting:

```r
liftover_output <- liftOver(gwas_ranges, chain)
Discarding unchained sequences: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 1, 20, 21, 22, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

My chain file seems fine on checking it (downloaded from UCSC genome browser), I align my chromosomes to have "chr" like the 38 chain does, and my gwas data is indeed in GRCh38 - what else could be going wrong?

My `gwas_ranges` looks like:

```r
head(gwas_ranges)
GRanges object with 6 ranges and 1 metadata column:
seqnames      ranges strand |    seqnames
<Rle>   <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character>
[1]       10 10708-10709      * |         chr
[2]       10 10904-10905      * |         chr
[3]       10 10942-10943      * |         chr
[4]       10 12112-12113      * |         chr
[5]       10 13850-13851      * |         chr
[6]       10 14537-14538      * |         chr
-------   seqinfo: 22 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

I also tried doing the liftover in python using hail. This ran without error, but the liftover of SNPs on chromosome 10 position 1234 would lift to chromosome 18 12369 . Here's my hail attempt:

```r
import hail as hl
hl.stop()
hl.init()

# Load the reference genomes and add the liftover chain file
rg38 = hl.get_reference("GRCh38")
rg37 = hl.get_reference("GRCh37")
local_chain_file = "/references_grch38_to_grch37.over.chain.gz" #downloaded from Hail's GCP
rg38.add_liftover(local_chain_file, rg37)

# Import GWAS data
gwas = hl.import_table('/gwas_sumstats_allchr.txt', 
                       types={'CHROM': 'str', 'GENPOS': 'int'})

# Standardize chromosome names in your GWAS data to match GRCh38
gwas = gwas.annotate(CHROM=hl.if_else(hl.literal('chr').contains(gwas.CHROM), gwas.CHROM, hl.literal('chr') + gwas.CHROM))

# Perform the liftover from GRCh38 to GRCh37
gwas = gwas.annotate(
    locus_grch38=hl.locus(gwas.CHROM, gwas.GENPOS, reference_genome='GRCh38'),
    locus_grch37=hl.liftover(hl.locus(gwas.CHROM, gwas.GENPOS, reference_genome='GRCh38'), 'GRCh37')
)

# Add new columns for CHROM_38 and GENPOS_38
gwas = gwas.annotate(
    CHROM_38=hl.if_else(hl.is_defined(gwas.locus_grch37), gwas.locus_grch37.contig, hl.null('str')),
    GENPOS_38=hl.if_else(hl.is_defined(gwas.locus_grch37), gwas.locus_grch37.position, hl.null('int'))
)

gwas = gwas.drop('locus_grch38', 'locus_grch37')

# Export the results
gwas.export('/gwas_sumstats_allchr_GRCh37.txt')
```

Here's some of the output I get from the hail run:

Head of `gwas_sumstats_GRCh38txt`:

```
CHROM   GENPOS  ID  ALLELE0 ALLELE1 A1FREQ  INFO    N   TEST    BETA    SE  CHISQ   LOG10P  p   MAF
10  10709   10:10709:G:A    G   A   0.0140284   0.420904    56210   ADD 0.143464    0.0384744   13.904  3.71581 0.000192393324862147    0.0140284
10  10905   10:10905:G:A    G   A   0.0352519   0.418554    56210   ADD -0.000990946    0.0246439   0.0016169   0.0141582   0.967925206925404   0.0352519
10  10943   10:10943:G:C    G   C   0.0653494   0.469298    56210   ADD -0.0130032  0.0173743   0.56013 0.342745    0.454208230910946   0.0653494
10  12113   10:12113:AC:A   AC  A   0.0390721   0.431839    56210   ADD 0.0386709   0.0230572   2.81293 1.02915 0.0935082652260488  0.0390721
```

Head of `gwas_sumstats_GRCh37.txt`:

```
CHROM   GENPOS  ID  A1FREQ  INFO    N   TEST    BETA    SE  CHISQ   LOG10P  p   MAF original_locus
18  10905   18:10905:G:A    0.0140284   0.420904    56210   ADD 0.143464    0.0384744   13.904  3.71581 0.000192393324862147    0.0140284   chr10:10709
18  11258   18:11258:G:A    0.0352519   0.418554    56210   ADD -0.000990946    0.0246439   0.0016169   0.0141582   0.967925206925404   0.0352519   chr10:10905
18  11296   18:11296:G:C    0.0653494   0.469298    56210   ADD -0.0130032  0.0173743   0.56013 0.342745    0.454208230910946   0.0653494   chr10:10943
18  12467   18:12467:AC:A   0.0390721   0.431839    56210   ADD 0.0386709   0.0230572   2.81293 1.02915 0.0935082652260488  0.0390721   chr10:12113
```

Comment: The BCFtools/liftover plugin [here](https://github.com/freeseek/score) is exactly aimed at handling GWAS summary statistics and it will do a much better job at dealing with summary statistics for indels